# SELECT DISTINCT field, but avoid some values

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table:

```
---------------------------
| id | capital_id | value |
---------------------------
|  1 |          1 |     a |
---------------------------
|  2 |          2 |     b |
---------------------------
|  3 |          2 |     c |
---------------------------
|  4 |          2 |     d |
---------------------------
|  5 |          3 |     b |
---------------------------
|  6 |          3 |     e |
---------------------------
|  7 |          4 |     f |
---------------------------
```

I need to select only **distinct** capital_id's, but **different** from one that has a value given.

To be more clear, I'll provide an example: If I have the record with id=5, I need to fetch all **distinct** capital_id's, different than 3 and with the value different from 'b' (so capital_id's to be fetched are: 1 and 4).

I managed to write the query like `SELECT id FROM table WHERE capital_id != $capital_id AND value != $value`, but duplicate capital_id's are fetched this way. I tried to add a `GROUP BY capital_id`, but then capital_id=2 is also fetched, although one of its values is 'b'.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT capital_id 
FROM tableName
WHERE capital_id <> $capital_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(value = $value) = 0
```

Comment: Seems a different approach to my problem. Could you explain a little bit what is the idea in your code? It'll help me understand better.

Comment: @linkyndy Query returns distinct (using the `GROUP BY` clause) `capital_id`s that a) are not **3** (`WHERE capital_id <> $capital_id`) And b) do not have any rows that the `value` column is **b** (`HAVING SUM(value = $value) = 0`)

Comment: So basically the `HAVING SUM(value = $value) = 0` eliminates all rows which have `value = $value`, **after** the records have been grouped (if one of the records grouped by same `capital_id` has `value = $value`, it gets deleted)?

Comment: @linkyndy Yes, It eliminates all **groups** that have a row which `value = $value`. See [Having Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: And also, why the query doesn't work if I add `AND value != $value` to the `WHERE` clause? Sorry for asking so many questions, but I am kind of a newbie in this are of MySQL.

Comment: @linkyndy `WHERE` predicate is tested on each **row**, `HAVING` is tested on each **group**

Comment: Oh, I think I understood now. Thank you for your answer and for being so patient :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE capital_id != $capital_id AND value != $value
```

Comment: OP want's distinct `capital_id` not `id`, Also, your query will return `capital_id` even in the case that there is a record with `value = b`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, isn't that taken care of with the `AND value != $value`?

Comment: @dirk No, If there are 2 rows with `capital_id=2`, 1 with `value='a'` and 1 with `value='b'`. The query posted **will** include the `capital_id` Since there is a row that doesn't match the predicate `value != $value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT capital_id
FROM tableName t
WHERE capital_id != $capital_id
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
               FROM tableName
               WHERE capital_id = t.capital_id
               AND value = $value)
GROUP BY capital_id
```